# Node.js: Determine file size on modification

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I'm watching a file in Node.js and would like to obtain the size of the file each time it changes. How can this be done with `fs.watchFile`?

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
fs.watchFile(file, function(curr, prev) {
  // determine file size
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I missed that the variables `curr` and `prev` that were returned from `fs.watchFile` were instances of `fs.Stats`. This would be the optimal solution:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.watchFile('file', function (curr, prev) {
  console.log(curr.size);
});
```

However, as of Node v0.8.0, `fs.watchFile` no longer uses `IOWatcher`, and now uses stat polling, which is slow and does not provide realtime updates. This was discussed on [GitHub](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3348).

From the Node [changelog](http://nodejs.org/changelog.html):

> Deprecate iowatcher, fs: fix fs.watchFile() (Ben Noordhuis)

Instead, an alternate solution is now `fs.watch` and `fs.stat`:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.watch('file', function (curr, prev) {
  fs.stat('file', function (err, stats) {
    console.log(stats.size);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 13):

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.watchFile('some.file', function () {
    fs.stat('some.file', function (err, stats) {
        console.log(stats.size);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `fs.stat` in the callback: `watchFile` just lets you know it changed, it doesn't report the change details.