# REST Upload to Skydrive without Content-Length

Tags: rest, onedrive

I'm trying to upload a file to Skydrive where I don't a-priori know the Content-Length. With other storage services I can do this with chunked HTTP upload, but Skydrive always complains about Content-Length being invalid.

Here are the full headers I'm sending:

```
PUT /v5.0/me/skydrive/files/skydrive_test.js?overwrite=ChooseNewName HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN_REDACTED>
host: apis.live.net
content-type: application/javascript
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Here's the response I get back:

```
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
transfer-encoding: chunked
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
server: Live-API/16.4.1731.327 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-http-live-request-id: API.c6afda25-2d9f-4248-9f49-001ccb3a9007
x-http-live-server: BAYMSG1010836
date: Wed, 15 May 2013 14:33:00 GMT

{   "error": {      "code": "request_invalid_content_length",
   "message": "The value for the Content-Length header isn't valid."   }}
```

Is there any way I can do this without setting Content-Length (i.e. using chunked encoding)?

I'm using node.js to do this, but it should apply equally with any language using the REST API, hence I haven't tagged this with a particular language.

For example Dropbox offers the Chunked Upload command: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#chunked-upload

And Google Drive, even though it says it wants Content-Length, doesn't need it for it's resumable upload API: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable

Is there an API I'm missing?

**Edit:** Things I've tried: Setting Content-Length: 0 results in it working, but the file is zero bytes. Setting Content-length:0 and Transfer-Encoding: chunked, results in the original error above.

Comment: Does it complain even if a valid value of `content-length` is provided in request header? like `content-length: 100`.

Comment: No, it works fine if I set the Content-Length heading. But I don't know it up front - the content is coming from a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a dummy `content-length` to see if it is acceptable. Otherwise set the file size.
If you are using `node.js` you can get the file size you are trying to upload and set the size to `content-length` in OCTETs. You can get the file size `requiring` the `fs` (filesystem) module in node.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.watchFile('some.file', function () {
    fs.stat('some.file', function (err, stats) {
        console.log(stats.size);
    });
});
```

[@Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257674/2051952)

Comment: I can't get the content-length up front. Imagine it's coming from a pipe. If I set a dummy content-length it disables chunked encoding.